# JList NullPointerException in valueChanged operation

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlist

here is my first JList:

```
JPanel classe = new JPanel();
class_list = new JList();
class_list.addListSelectionListener(this);
JScrollPane classeScrollPane = new JScrollPane(class_list);
classeScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175,405));
classe.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Classes"));
classe.add(classeScrollPane);
```

here is the second:

```
JPanel relation = new JPanel();
relation_list = new JList();
relation_list.addListSelectionListener(this);
JScrollPane relationScrollPane = new JScrollPane(relation_list);
relationScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(220,130));
relation.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Relations"));
relation.add(relationScrollPane);
```

here is my valueChanged operation:

```
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
    JList source = (JList) e.getSource();
    String value = (String)source.getSelectedValue();
    if (value.length() > 0){
        if (source == class_list){
            //if(!relation_list.isSelectionEmpty()) relation_list.clearSelection();
            Class_object co = declaration.getClass(value);
            attribut_list.setListData(co.getAttributes().toArray());
            operation_list.setListData(co.getOperations().toArray());
            if(declaration.getGeneralization(value) !=null){
                subClass_list.setListData(declaration.getGeneralization(value).getSubClasses().toArray());
            }
            //clear JList if there is no correspondent subclass
            else subClass_list.setListData(new String[2]);
            //add relation content to relation panel
            DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
            related_association = declaration.getAssociation(value);
            for(Association asso : related_association){
                model.addElement("(R)"+asso.getName());
            }
            related_aggregation = declaration.getAggregation(value);
            for(Aggregation agg : related_aggregation){
                model.addElement("(A)"+agg.getName());
            }
            relation_list.setModel(model);
        }
        if (source == relation_list){
            int focused_list = source.getSelectedIndex();
            if(focused_list < related_association.size()){
                details.setText(related_association.get(focused_list).toString());
            }
            else {
                details.setText(related_aggregation.get(focused_list-related_association.size()).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, when we click on item in the first JList, it displays in the second JList something (for example a variable name of this item). Then we click on item in the second JList, it displays more information about this item in a JTextArea. So you have to click first jlist to display second jlist then click second jlist to display detail information.
Here is the problem, after I have clicked first jlist and second jlist, I click another item in first JList, a NullPointerException occurs in line "

> if (value.length() > 0){

I understand that the error occurs because the variable value is null, but I don't know why value is null.
Could anyone tell me whats wrong with my code. Thanks alot.

Comment: What's wrong is that value is null, meaning that there is no selected value. Check it's not null before calling a method on it. Also use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting%28%29 and don't do anything while the value is adjusting.

Comment: the display is ok when I switching between items in same jlist,but not ok when i have chose an item in both JList and then try to change item in first jlist.@JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

During a change in selection, the currently selected item is "deselected", this means that, momentarily, nothing is selected, the `ListSelectionListener`s are notified of this change, this is where your `null` value is coming from.

Then the selection is changed to the newly selected item and the `ListSelecitonListener`s are notified again.

You can test for this through the use of [`ListSelectionEvent#getValueIsAdjusting`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting())

The reason this occurs the second time you select a value is because the deselection event notification does not occur, only the selection event...

Comment: but i have tested them using isSelectionEmpty() in both jlist, both return false.

Comment: Test the event to make sure that the selection process is not in a state of mutation, it's possible that the `JList` doesn't actually know yet that the selection has changed.  Use the information which is most accurate, the event information

Comment: The other possibility is that the `JList` you are trying to get information from isn't the `JList` which is on the screen...

Comment: You mean that for two JList , if I make a selection in a Jlist, the previous selection in other Jlist would be deselected?  So how to keep other JList seleted?

Comment: No, this is just one `JList`, the `source` of the event, in most cases a change in selection will raise two events, a `DESELECT` and a `SELECT` event for the single `JList`...

Comment: In my testing, when `valueIsAdjusting` returns `true`, `isSelectionEmpty` is `false` and visa-verse. Based on your comments, this would suggest that there is something else going on in your code which we don't know about

Comment: what should i do to fix this problem? I still have no clue.

Comment: Check the events `isValueAdjusting` property, if it is `true`, ignore the event...